# Express route not correctly behaving

Tags: node.js, express, routes

In my `app.js`, among other routes, I have a route specified as...

```
app.route('/api/patients/:id/medication').get(MedicationController.all).post(MedicationController.add)
```

The controller for this route, and all others is pulled in from an external module. The `GET` method for this route, however, is acting very strange while the `POST` works perfectly fine.

When I do a `GET` request to the route above with a valid `uuid` in the URL for the `id` parameter (e.g. `/api/patients/bd4d6d44-3af3-4224-afef-d7e9a876025b/medication`), there are no errors, but I get the response...

```
{
    status:200,
    data: []
}
```

This doesn't make any sense to me because I had updated the `MedicationController.all` function to also include another field for testing, so even if there were no results for the query, the response **should** be...

```
{
    status: 200,
    data: [],
    test: 'TEST FIELD'
}
```

Another thing, that doesn't make sense to me is that I can put in `/api/patients/bd4d6d44-3af3-4224-afef-d7e9a876025b/medafsdghads`, or some other garbage sub route after the `uuid` and still returns the same strange response.

In case it matters, here is the actual handler...

```
export function all(req, res) {
  let id = req.params.id

  r.table('Patients').get(id).getField('prescriptions').run().then((results) => {
    console.log(results)
    return res.json({ status: 200, data: results, testField: 'TEST FIELD' })
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
    return res.json({ status: 400, message: 'There was an error finding the medication of patient ' + id, data: error })
  })
}
```

Here are also **all** of the routes I have currently implemented as well...

```
/*********************
* PATIENT API ROUTES *
*********************/
app.route('/api/patients').get(PatientController.all).post(PatientController.add)
app.route('/api/patients/:last/:first').get(PatientController.findName)
app.route('/api/patients/:id').get(PatientController.findId)

/************************
* MEDICATION API ROUTES *
************************/
app.route('/api/patients/:id/medication').get(MedicationController.all).post(MedicationController.add)
app.route('/api/patients/:id/medication/expiration').put(MedicationController.updateAllExpirations)
app.route('/api/patients/:patId/medication/expiration/:medId').put(MedicationController.updateExpiration)

/*************************
* INSTITUTION API ROUTES *
*************************/
app.route('/api/institutions').get(InstitutionController.all).post(InstitutionController.add)
app.route('/api/institutions/:id').get(InstitutionController.findId)
app.route('/api/institutions/:name').get(InstitutionController.findName)
```

Comment: `console.log(results)` what does that output?

Comment: @CharlieFish just an empty array, but I'm wondering if the handler mapping is screwed up somehow because the test field of the response isn't being included

Comment: If it's calling that `console.log` then it's calling the correct function and everything. And data must be correct then since the `console.log` is an empty array. The only problem is that testField. Did you make sure to do the obvious things like restart your server and everything? That's a tricky one. Any other things you noticed while debugging?

Comment: @CharlieFish yeah I've been restarting and rebuilding after every change I tried. All of my handlers have that console.log though and any poor query could result in an empty array. The only other thing I could thing of is if I commented out the route that I'm talking about in my app.js, it still happened hahaha

Comment: @CharlieFish if you want to see all of the code, the git repo is https://github.com/callensm/meditrack-site

Comment: So if you have `console.log` in all of your handlers why not just  add a custom `console.log` to that specific handler and see if it's the correct one getting called?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123467/discussion-between-charlie-fish-and-m-callens).

Comment: @CharlieFish I changed the `console.log` to something unique to test, and nothing changed...

Comment: So it's probably calling the wrong method. I would go through and try to find what method it actually is calling but doing some debugging and some `console.log` statements.

Comment: @CharlieFish solved! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an overlap of routes that match the same URL:

```
// This one:
app.route('/api/patients/:last/:first')

// And this one: 
app.route('/api/patients/:id/medication')
```

Express doesn't match the most logical route, it matches the first declared route that matches the request. In your case, `/api/patients/bd4d6d44-3af3-4224-afef-d7e9a876025b/medication` matches the first route.

You should declare more specific routes (with less parameters to match) first.

Comment: I discovered this seconds before you posted! Oops! Thank you so much!!